# Convert C# string to C char*

Tags: c#, c, string, type-conversion

I want to convert a C# `String` to a C `char*`. The thing is, I can't use a fixed statement, since it has to be compatible with Default C, since all my strings in C are `char*`.

I've tryed over bytearrays, but I only managed to convert it to `char[]`, `byte[]`, etc., but never to `char*`.

Anyone knows how to do that?

I've searched quite a bit, not found anything helpful (most recommended using a fixed statement, which may make it not compatible with Default C...)

The thing is, my function needs a `char*` as argument, since the function will be used in Default C, and the `char*` is the return result of the function. (basically, you pass the pointer as argument, and it assigns the result to the address of that pointer. Does that even work as I hope?)

Comment: `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`. Don't forget to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` when you're done. Or, if you're using P/Invoke, use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`

Comment: You need to look into pointer types. See this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: I don't really get the whole idea of COM and Pinvoke... I have to read into it, since it seems really important

Comment: C# is managed and c++ is not.  So to pass data into a c++ dll you must move the c# data to un-managed memory space.  So you need to convert to a IntPtr object in c# which is a pointer to any data type in c#.

Comment: So I need to declare a pointer outside of my default memory by manually allocating it, then I can access it via my C DLL? The thing is, I declare the variable in C, then I just pass the address over, amd I just want to take that address and assign it a string that is compatible with C.